# Twitter API XML Access

Tags: python, twitter

I'm playing around with Twitter's API, but I've come across something I'm confused about.

I'm trying to get a list of friends/followers from a public profile, and I could get the user IDs in XML with this URL:

```
http://twitter.com/followers/ids.xml?screen_name=[namehere]
```

But then I read the documentations on the Twitter API website that says accessing a user's friends/followers requires authentication. If so, then why can I access the url above and get user IDs?

The reason I'm wondering about this is also because I wanted to write a script in python with the python-twitter library, but the `twitter.User.GetFriends()` or `twitter.User.GetFollowers()` functions return a message saying I have to be authenticated.

Are these inconsistencies from Twitter's part that will be adressed soon? Could I rely on parsing the XML output with a parser instead of the twitter library?

Comment: Why? Because eother the docs are wrong, or it's a bug, or you misunderstood something. How reliable the API is is only known to twitter. Ask them.

Comment: Wild guess: You can access that info from twitter because it's public anyway. Glancing at the source code, it looks like the equivalent function is `Api.GetFollowerIDs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting just the IDs of the followers via *[followers/ids](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/friends/ids)* does not require authentication, and neither do the calls to *[users/show](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/show)*, *[statuses/friends](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/friends)* and *[statuses/followers](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/followers)*. The linked documentation reflects this.  My guess is that your python-twitter library, and not Twitter, is requiring you to authenticate, or those library methods are calling *[users/lookup](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/lookup)* (which does require authentication) under the hood.

You should be able to click the following links without the need to authenticate:

http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids/arcain.xml

http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/arcain.xml

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/friends/arcain.xml

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/followers/arcain.xml

Some of the timeline methods related to friends and followers, like [statuses/home_timeline](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/home_timeline) (for fetching the target user's and her followers' tweets) and [statuses/friends_timeline](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/friends_timeline) (for fetching the target user's friends' aggregate timeline) *do* require authentication.